# Issue in Android OTA creation using the ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files tool

Tags: android

I built the Android open source project (AOSP) for the Qualcomm using the steps mention at [OTA Package tool](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/tools)

Now I want to create the full and incremental OTA package for that also i refer the same command mention in the above link but i am getting following error:

```
xxx@SRS-DT-041:/media/xxx/external/xxxx/apq8096au-la-1-3_ap_standard_oem.git/LINUX/android_working$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files /media/xxx/external/xxx/apq8096au-la-1-3_ap_standard_oem.git/LINUX/android_working/dist_output_xxx/msm8996-ota-eng.xxx.zip  OTA.zipTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1996, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1887, in main
    OPTIONS.info_dict = common.LoadInfoDict(input_zip)
  File "/media/xxx/external/xxx/apq8096au-la-1-3_ap_standard_oem.git/LINUX/android_working/build/make/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 169, in LoadInfoDict
    raise ValueError("can't find META/misc_info.txt in input target-files")
ValueError: can't find META/misc_info.txt in input target-files
xxx@SRS-DT-041:/media/xxx/external/xxx/apq8096au-la-1-3_ap_standard_oem.git/LINUX/android_working$
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that you are not using the "target files" for generating your OTA. The "target file" seems to be an generated OTA in the out-folder.

The syntax is:

```
$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files <target_file_as_input> <ota_file_as_output>
```

The target files usually resides in:

```
out/dist/*-target_files-*.zip
```

In my AOSP I do:

```
$ ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files ota/dist/dajo-target_files-eng.david.zip ota.zip
```